# OpenMP Stack overflow diagnosis

Tags: c++, openmp, stack-overflow

I'm running a program with an OpenMP threaded function. It works for a smaller problem size, but gives a segfault at some point as I increase the problem size.

I've read that this has to do with stack overflow, however my static variables are of fixed size, so I don't see the stack size changing with problem size. Sample code below:

```
float myfunc(float *bigArray1FromMain, float *bigArray2FromMain, int N)
{
// bigArray1FromMain has been malloc'd to accommodate N floats
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int localArray[2];
        int i;

        #pragma omp for
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
           localArray[0] = someIndex(i);
           localArray[1] = someIndex(i);
           bigArray1FromMain[i] = bigArray2FromMain(localArray[0]) 
                                  + bigArray2FromMain(localArray[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this code break as `N` increases? My understanding is that each thread has it's own copy of `localArray` and `i`, which require 3 ints on the stack. This shouldn't change with problem size.

If `localArray[0] or [1]` contain the same integers for different threads, then two threads may be accessing the same elements of `bigArray2FromMain` at the same time. But since it's not being modified, I am assuming that shouldn't be a problem. Does this need to be enclosed in an `atomic` or `critical` clause?

Another possibility is that `someIndex()` is buggy, but I don't think that's the case.

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: AFAICT, the code snippet shown is correct, and so are your assumptions. Two possibilities I see: 1/ some memory exhaustion when N gets bigger; or 2/ some bug in the code elsewhere. Either ways, try to run your code through a debugger and/or a memory checker like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Be careful, by default variables that are not indicated in the #pragma omp have "shared" visibility by default except for the loop counter (i in your case). So all threads share localArray and they are likely to access improper locations because other threads may have changed their value. Still, this is not likely to be the reason of your fault. For that, I suggest you to generate a coredump an inspect it. Maybe someIndex() is not threadsafe?

Comment: BTW, I assume your arrays don't overlap. You should use `restrict` to inform the compile that they don't overlap for optimization.  Do `(float * __restrict bigArray1FromMain, float * __restrict bigArray2FromMain, int N)`

Comment: Does the scalar code work fine? I mean does you code work without OpenMP?

Comment: `someIndex()`is actually a black box for us. If you return some index that is beyond the size of the arrays  you may find unexpected behaviours. You should add that function to the question

Comment: It was a bug outside the function. I had bigArray1FromMain malloc'd incorrectly. Lot of useful comments, though. Thanks.